# Break a for loop if the next element does not exist

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

```
/**
 * This method clicks an element if it exist
 * @param by
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void optionalClick(By by) throws InterruptedException
{
    log.divider("Check if Element Exist or Not......");     
    //String continueFB_Page = "";
    //continueFB_Page = driver.getPageSource();
    Thread.sleep(4000);     
    if(driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed())         
    {
        log.log("Element IS present... Clicked");
        log.log("Indo App IS NOT installed on FB acct.......Signing in for the first time..");
        driver.findElement(by).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);         
    }

}

/**
 * This method Signs user in using FB social signIn 
 * Takes the Constant signIn variable as the Link
 * 
 * @param link
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void signInFacebook(String link) throws InterruptedException {
    log.header("USER SIGN IN VIA FACEBOOK");
    log.step("Click the Sign In Link");
    clickLink(link);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    log.log("click success.......");
    log.step("Click 'Sign in with Facebook' Link ");


    // Store the current window handle
    String parentHandle  = driver.getWindowHandle();
    //boolean presentPage = driver.equals(parentHandle);


    // Perform the click operation that opens new window
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.FB_SIGN_IN)).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);     

    // Switch to new window opened
    log.divider("Facebook Login Screen.....Enter Details Below");
    for (String childHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(childHandle);          

        if (!childHandle.equals(parentHandle)) {                
            log.step("Enter Email address");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.FB_EMAIL_TXTBOX))
                    .sendKeys(CONSTANTs.EMAIL_ADDRESS);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            log.step("Enter password");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.FB_PASSWORD_TXTBOX))
                    .sendKeys(CONSTANTs.FB_PASSWORD);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            log.step("Click Log_In button");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.LOG_IN)).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000); 

            log.log("am here ... 1");
            WebDriver switchPage = driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
            log.log("am here ... 2");
            if(switchPage.getWindowHandle().contains(parentHandle))
            {
                driver.switchTo().window(childHandle);
                optionalClick(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.OK_CONTINUE_AS));
                driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
            }else
            {
                log.log("Indo App Already exist on Users Fb acct ... Move to next screen");
                //driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
            }
            log.log("END....... ");
            break;
        }


    }
    //log.log("Indo App Already exist on Users Fb acct ... Move to next screen");
    //log.log("Element NOT present ... Move to next screen");   
    //Thread.sleep(3000);       





    Thread.sleep(2000);
    log.divider("Check if User is Signed In already with a different account or NOT........ pls wait");
    driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);

    //WebElement signedInAlready = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.ALREADY_SIGNED_UP_SCREEN));      
    //String ggg = signedInAlready.getText();

    String signedInAlready = "";
    signedInAlready = driver.getPageSource();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    if(signedInAlready.contains("Already Signed up?"))
    {

    log.log("User is Signed in Already with another account");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.ALREADY_SIGNED_UP_PASSWD_TXTBOX)).sendKeys(CONSTANTs.NATIVE_PASSWORD);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.ALREADY_SIGNED_UP_BUTTON)).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    log.log("User successfully logged in, ... Linked Account together.....");
    }
    else 
    {
    log.log("Successfully Logged in Using FB.");}       
}
```

The problem am having is when the code runs the first time `optionalClick(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.OK_CONTINUE_AS))` this code runs as the element is present. but when the code runs the second time, the `optionalClick(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.OK_CONTINUE_AS))` this code should not run as the element won't exist.

Now I want the else to work but am getting a freeze. I think my problem is switching in between screens, if am right but am totally confused here.

Comment: test with if statement that the element exists

Comment: I have tested using if statement but freezes when it does not find the element. if the element exist, it works fine but once it cant find the element, it freezes.. Below is the error i get if the element does not exist: Below is the error am getting:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)

Comment: catch the Exception, when it occurs u break your loop

Comment: @Me Good Guy .... yippie.. it works perfectly,... Have being on this for like 2days now. I tried using the try/catch but guess in the wrong way. Thanks a mill. You're a life saver

Comment: Working code below                                                                                `try{
    if(switchPage.getWindowHandle().contains(parentHandle))
    {
     driver.switchTo().window(childHandle);
     optionalClick(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTs.OK_CONTINUE_AS));
     driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
    }     
    log.log("END....... ");
    //break;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     log.log("Indo App Already exist on Users Fb acct ... Move to next screen");
     //driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
    }break;`

Comment: Nice =D Happy it worked, thank u :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For optionalClick method, use [explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits). If element is found with in 10 seconds (as per code), element will be clicked. Otherwise a timeout exception is raised and its handled in catch block.

```
try{
   (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by)));
   driver.findElement(by).click();
   }
catch(TimeoutException te){
}
```

Comment: ......Thanks for the hint. i just tried that and worked perfectly, making my code even more proficient. Thanks a mill for all your help. So if am right, the WebDriverWait is basically same as thread.sleep only it checks if element exist while waiting? right?.

Comment: @Joe, yes explicit wait will halt execution until the element is seen, rather than Thread.sleep, which will simply suspend the execution till the given time. Thread.sleep is advised not to be used in the automation scripts.

Comment: @Joe, if the answer helped, pls accept the answer and upvote.

Comment: Tanx once again, yes your answer did help but am a new user and i need to get a minimum of 15 reputation before my feedback can show on screen. Sorry about that. Hope you understand.

Comment: yep i got it now. upvote requires 15 rep. answer can be accepted with your rep also. pls check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: DONE.. tanx a mill :)